# What's the simplest way to rename a schema in an AWS Aurora (MySQL) database?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I'm hoping to do it without dumping and restoring, but if that's the only way then any pitfalls would be very welcome info!

Thank you.